# Pandas: reshaping dataframe by splitting columns in a column and a variable

Tags: python, pandas, melt

I have the following dataframe that I am trying to melt:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2014', periods=4)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.eye(4, ), index=dates, columns=['A_var1', 'A_var2', 'B_var1', 'B_var2'])
print(df)

             A_var1  A_var2  B_var1  B_var2
2014-01-01     1.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
2014-01-02     0.0     1.0     0.0     0.0
2014-01-03     0.0     0.0     1.0     0.0
2014-01-04     0.0     0.0     0.0     1.0
```

I want to obtain the following:

```
            type    var1    var2  
2014-01-01   A      1.0     0.0    
2014-01-01   B      0.0     0.0    
2014-01-02   A      0.0     1.0     
2014-01-02   B      0.0     0.0  
2014-01-03   A      0.0     0.0    
2014-01-03   B      1.0     0.0
2014-01-04   A      0.0     0.0     
2014-01-04   B      0.0     1.0
```

Any idea on how to do that efficiently? I know I can use the melt function but I can't get it to work in that context.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `stack` on multi-indexed columns.

```
In [304]: df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)

In [305]: df.stack(0).reset_index(1)
Out[305]:
           level_1  var1  var2
2014-01-01       A   1.0   0.0
2014-01-01       B   0.0   0.0
2014-01-02       A   0.0   1.0
2014-01-02       B   0.0   0.0
2014-01-03       A   0.0   0.0
2014-01-03       B   1.0   0.0
2014-01-04       A   0.0   0.0
2014-01-04       B   0.0   1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is with the [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), using the `.value` placeholder:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.pivot_longer(names_to=("type", ".value"), 
                names_sep="_", 
                ignore_index=False, 
                sort_by_appearance = True)

          type  var1  var2
2014-01-01   A   1.0   0.0
2014-01-01   B   0.0   0.0
2014-01-02   A   0.0   1.0
2014-01-02   B   0.0   0.0
2014-01-03   A   0.0   0.0
2014-01-03   B   1.0   0.0
2014-01-04   A   0.0   0.0
2014-01-04   B   0.0   1.0
```

The `.value` keeps the part of the column associated with it as header, while the rest goes into the `type` column.